# Replace word instances with its count attached to it

Tags: text-processing, sed

I have a file which contains word 'name' multiple times ( 250 times ).

I need to replace every instance of 'name' with its count attached to it as name_1, name_2, name_3....name_250.

Can I do this using sed ?

What flags I need to use ?

Comment: Will the name always appear as a separate word (i.e., either at the beginning of the line or preceded by whitespace, AND either at the end of the line or followed by whitespace), or might it be contiguous with punctuation or other characters?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A job for `perl`:

```
perl -pe 's/\bname\b\K/"_".++$n/ge'
```

Answer (score 1):

Because this involves arithmetic, this is not a good problem for `sed`.  However, `awk` can handle it:

```
awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="name") {c++;$i=$i"_"c} }} 1'
```

For example:

```
$ echo  a name b name name c d name | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="name") {c++;$i=$i"_"c} }} 1'
a name_1 b name_2 name_3 c d name_4
```

#### Explanation:

- `{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) { if ($i=="name") {c++;$i=$i"_"c} }}`

  This `for` loop iterates over each word found in the input.  If the word is `name`, then the counter variable `c` is incremented and its value is appended to the word.
- `1`

  In the `awk` language, this cryptic shorthand means print the whole line.

As a side-effect, extraneous white space will be removed.  This includes leading and trailing white space on each line and inter-word spaces are reduced to a single blank.

Answer (score 0):

In Simple Bash Script

```
#!/bin/bash
count=0
search="linux"

while read line
do
      for word in ${line}
      do
           if [[ $word == $search ]]
           then
                printf "${word}_${count} "
                ((count++))
           else 
                printf "$word "
           fi
      done
      echo 
done < input_file
```